# How to enable continues speech to text and text to speech in ios using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c ios development.I am try to implement continues speech to text and text to speech in ios using objective c. speech to text using the https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=prodDev
 nuance developer code and text to speech using below coding -

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
     AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init]autorelease];
    [syn speakUtterance:utterance];
```

above coding app will be working good in simulators(like as iphone 5s and 6s).
but once I try to run this app in real device (like iphone 5c and 6s) continues speech to text working good but text to speech to text not working.

at the same time I have tried bellow coding text to speech. this will be working simulator and real device also.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Some text"];
    [utterance setRate:0.5f];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
    }
```

and I have tried following way STT and TTS. it is also working good for simulators but real device STT working good and TTS is not working.

```
      - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
     [SpeechKit setupWithID:@"my setup id"
                              host:@"my host"
                              port:443
                            useSSL:NO
                          delegate:nil];

       [self beginrecord];

        synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance     speechUtteranceWithString:@"Some text"];
        [utterance setRate:0.5f];
        [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];


    }

- (void) beginrecord {


    [searchBox resignFirstResponder];
    [serverBox resignFirstResponder];
    [portBox resignFirstResponder];

    if (transactionState == TS_RECORDING) {
        [voiceSearch stopRecording];
    }
    else if (transactionState == TS_IDLE) {
        SKEndOfSpeechDetection detectionType;
        NSString* recoType;
        NSString* langType;

        transactionState = TS_INITIAL;
        detectionType = SKShortEndOfSpeechDetection;
        recoType = SKSearchRecognizerType;


        langType = @"en_US";



        //   NSLog(@"Recognizing type:'%@' Language Code: '%@' using end-of-speech detection:%d.", recoType, langType, detectionType);

        if (voiceSearch) [voiceSearch release];

        voiceSearch = [[SKRecognizer alloc] initWithType:recoType
                                               detection:detectionType
                                                language:langType
                                                delegate:self];
    }

}
```

no error in console log.how to resolve this problem. please guide me thanks.

Comment: how to  speech to text convert sir please let me know ?

Comment: @ Ramani Hitesh pls use siri speech kit for speech to text conversion.. pls check this example https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/

Comment: but sir my project task for convert audio file to text file  resolve this one

Comment: record the audio in your mobile app and send the audio files in your server side after you will convert audio file to text file using google-cloud-speech-api https://ctrlq.org/code/20280-google-cloud-speech-api. thanks